# I need a header as the first photo, but the only thing I can do is the second photo

Tags: header-footer

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tablehere}
{\def\@captype{table}}
{}
\makeatother


\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO, LE]{\framebox[9\width][s]{se separan}}


\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE, RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO, CE]{Chapter \thechapter}

\makeatletter
\let \ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
%  \input{title}

  \chapter{Introduction}
  ...

  \chapter{Background}
  ...

  \chapter{Conclusion}
  ...

  \newpage
  afjdajf
  \newpage
  sagfajg

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't shout in the question title (avoid ALL UPPERCASE text). And skip the “please help me” bit: People will be *less* inclined to help because of it. Skip the “thank you” as well: The way to thank people around here is to upvote and/or accept their answer if you find it useful. Also, if you indent your code by four spaces, it will be appropriately displayed. You can achieve that very simply by selecting the code and hitting the `{ }` button above the input field. (I see that a helpful person has already implemented my advice. Good.)

Comment: OKEY @HaraldHanche-Olsen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For diagonal lines, you need TikZ.  Also, fancyhdr tends to change `\headheight` from one page to the next, so I used `\myheight` instead.  (TikZ draws slightly outside the bounds.)  The strut is used to align the page number and "Chapter".

Needless to say, you can always adjust the position of the text relative to the tikz coordinates.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{tablehere}
{\def\@captype{table}}
{}
\makeatother

\newlength{\myheight}% fancyhdr changes \headheight from one page to the next.
\setlength{\myheight}{\dimexpr \ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox+.666em}
\setlength{\headheight}{\dimexpr \myheight+0.5pt}% width of tikz lines

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[CE]{\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[draw=black,fill=orange]  
    (0,0) -- (.7\textwidth,0) -- (.8\textwidth,\myheight) -- (0,\myheight) -- cycle;
  \path[draw=black,fill=gray]
    (.7\textwidth,0) -- (\textwidth,0) -- (\textwidth,\myheight) -- (.8\textwidth,\myheight) -- cycle;
  \path (0,0) node[above right] {\chaptername~\thechapter\strut}
    (\textwidth,0) node[above left] {\thepage\strut};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\begin{tikzpicture}\path[draw=black,fill=gray]
    (0,0) -- (.3\textwidth,0) -- (.2\textwidth,\myheight) -- (0,\myheight) -- cycle;
  \path[draw=black,fill=orange]
    (.3\textwidth,0) -- (\textwidth,0) -- (\textwidth,\myheight) -- (.2\textwidth,\myheight) -- cycle;
  \path (0,0) node[above right] {\thepage\strut}
    (\textwidth,0) node[above left] {\chaptername~\thechapter\strut};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\makeatletter
\let \ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
%  \input{title}

  \chapter{Introduction}
  ...

  \chapter{Background}
  ...

  \chapter{Conclusion}
  ...

  \newpage
  afjdajf
  \newpage
  sagfajg

\end{document}
```

Comment: merci @John Kormylo